# same command but different output encoding

Tags: powershell, encoding

UPDATE:

Just discovery if perform `chcp 65001 & chcp 850` between tests, and than continue testing, it print correct diacritics once just after chcp changes, but than continue printing wrong diacritic.

---

open console window with default codepage 850

run command

`echo asdbščřoldTxtéíáuijhj | powershell.exe -command "$Input | foreach-object {$_ -replace 'xté', 'ABC'} | ForEach-Object { [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8; Write-Output $_ }"`

and get following output

`asdbscroldTABCíáuijhj`

when press UP arrow and repeat command, got following output

`asdb┼í─ì┼ÖoldTxt├®├¡├íuijhj`

Why exact same command produce output with different encoding?

Comment: Which console? Which PowerShell version?

Comment: cmd.exe in WIN10.0.19045.2965

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'asdbščřoldTxtéíáuijhj'.encode( 'utf_8').decode( 'cp850')` returns `'asdb┼í─ì┼ÖoldTxt├®├¡├íuijhj'`. The same in PowerShell: `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 850).GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'UTF-8').GetBytes( 'asdbščřoldTxtéíáuijhj'))` returns `asdb┼í─ì┼ÖoldTxt├®├¡├íuijhj`

Comment: Understand this, but my question is why it behave first and second time differently. Nothing was changed between tests, command just executed twice

Answer (score 1):

Set console encoding to `UTF8`<sup>1</sup> using `chcp 65001` *before* running PowerShell first time (and *let it be inside PowerShell* itself):

```
chcp 65001
echo asdbščřoldTxtéíáuijhj | powershell.exe -noprofile -command "$Input | foreach-object {$_ -replace 'xté', 'ABC'} | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_ }"
echo asdbščřoldTxtéíáuijhj | powershell.exe -noprofile -command "$Input | foreach-object {$_ -replace 'xté', 'ABC'} | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_ }"
```

> ```
> asdbščřoldTABCíáuijhj
> asdbščřoldTABCíáuijhj
> ```

[Standard Handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/definitions#standard-handles) are then inherited from the parent automatically into PowerShell, incl. their encoding… For proof, change code page to either valid value and then run

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "& {[System.Console]::InputEncoding; [System.Console]::OutputEncoding}"
```

### Explanation

based (not only) on the [Windows Console documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/), and on my own discoveries.

Encoding of [standard handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/definitions#standard-handles) `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` is treated differently in console applications `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` (`pwsh.exe`):

**In `powershell.exe`/`pwsh.exe`)**: [`\[System.Console\]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console)

- `[System.Console]::InputEncoding` gets or sets the encoding the console uses to **read input** (`STDIN`).
- `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` gets or sets the encoding the console uses to **write output** (`STDOUT`, `STDERR`, `WARNING`, `VERBOSE`, and other [output handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams)).

**In `cmd.exe`**: `chcp` command displays or sets the active code page number:

- `CHCP [nnn]` changes the active console Code Page (**all input and output** handles `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, while
- `CHCP`       shows the current code page retrieved from *`STDIN`*, e.g prints the codepage of the *input* assuming that it is the same of the *ouput* (a pretty long lasting issue, see [[Undocumented] `CHCP` forum](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=84)).

The latter `CHCP` command problem seems to be pertinent to Windows console host (Microsoft proprietary) `conhost.exe`.
Unfortunately, the problem survives even with *modern* console host (open source collaborated) `openconsole.exe`, e.g. in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal).

**Example**: let us have a (BOM-less) `UTF-8` file:

```
chcp 65001
type escrzyUTF8.txt
```

> ```
> ě š  č   ř   ž   ý   á   í   é
> Ě Š  Č   Ř   Ž   Ý   Á   Í   É
> ```

Easy to invoke a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case:

```
chcp 852
type escrzyUTF8.txt
```

> ```
> ─ŤÔÇë┼íÔÇëÔÇë─ŹÔÇëÔÇëÔÇë┼Ö ÔÇë┬á┼ż ÔÇë┬á├Ż ÔÇë┬á├í ÔÇë┬á├ş ÔÇë┬á├ę
> ─ÜÔÇë┼áÔÇëÔÇë─îÔÇëÔÇëÔÇë┼ś ÔÇë┬á┼Ż ÔÇë┬á├Ł ÔÇë┬á├ü ÔÇë┬á├Ź ÔÇë┬á├ë
> ```

Then, running the following code snippet proves the `CHCP` issue:

```
:: set `stdin` and `stdout` encoding to code page 852 
chcp 852
:: set `stdout` encoding to `UTF8`
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "& {[System.Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;}"
:: get `stdin` and `stdout` encoding (852 and 65001, respectively)
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "& {[System.Console]::InputEncoding|Select-Object CodePage,EncodingName; [System.Console]::OutputEncoding|Select-Object CodePage,EncodingName;}"
:: `CHCP` shows `stdin` encoding: Active code page: 852 
chcp
:: although `stdout` encoding is `UTF8`
type escrzyUTF8.txt
```

[image]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Or any other suitable encoding as follows:</sup>

```
chcp 852
echo asdbščřoldTxtéíáuijhj | powershell.exe -noprofile -command "$Input | foreach-object {$_ -replace 'xté', 'ABC'} | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_ }"
echo asdbščřoldTxtéíáuijhj | powershell.exe -noprofile -command "$Input | foreach-object {$_ -replace 'xté', 'ABC'} | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_ }"
echo asdbščřoldTxtéíáuijhj | powershell.exe -noprofile -command "$Input | foreach-object {$_ -replace 'xté', 'ABC'} | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_ }"
```

> ```
> asdbščřoldTABCíáuijhj
> asdbščřoldTABCíáuijhj
> asdbščřoldTABCíáuijhj
> ```